# Break out of double foreach in Scala

Tags: scala

I have to return true or false based on field value in inner set item. My loops is as follow

```
myChoice.category.foreach(category => {
  category.flavours.foreach(flavour=> {
    if (flavour.available) true
  })
})
false
```

It shoudld break and return true as soon as I have true on available but its returning false all the time. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have your dataset to work with, but perhaps this might do it.

```
myChoice.category.exists(_.flavours.exists(_.available))
```

Answer (score 3):

Scala doesn't have `continue` or `break`. Because it is a fully functional language, every expression (including a loop) must have a value. Moreover, it tries to break out of the imperative style of initializing variables and mutating them over the course of a loop. Instead, scala encourages you to use a functional style, i.e. use methods that apply to data structures as a whole to transform/search for the desired result.

For your case, you're clearly looking to see if any of the flavors have their `available` field set to `true`. Thus you could flatMap the whole nested collection to a List of Boolean, and take the `or` of the whole collection:

```
val anyAvaliable = myChoice.category.flatMap(a => a.flavours).reduce( (flavour1,flavour2) => flavour1.available || flavour2.available)
```

jwvh's solution is even more concise. There are many ways of accomplishing essentially the same thing. Don't fight the language, have it fight for you!

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: the below solution is provided for completeness, but jwvh's answer should be preferred for this case and generally speaking there are better alternatives. In particular, note that `return` from inside a lambda is implemented using exceptions, so 1) it may perform much worse than normal method calls; 2) if you are careless you can accidentally catch it.

If this is the last thing you need to do in the method, you can just use `return`:

```
myChoice.category.foreach(category => {
  category.flavours.foreach(flavour=> {
    if (flavour.available) return true
  })
})
false
```

If it isn't, you can extract a method (including a local one):

```
def foo = {
  ...

  val myChoice = ...

  def hasAvailableFlavorsMethod() = {
    myChoice.category.foreach(category => {
      category.flavours.foreach(flavour=> {
        if (flavour.available) return true
      })
    })
    false
  }

  val hasAvailableFlavors = hasAvailableFlavorsMethod()

  ...
}
```